# How can i create a ggplot bar chart without overlapping bars?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, multiple-columns

My problem is, that i need to create bar charts without the bars overlapping each other. A small example of my data is:

```
`structure(list(Variable = c("VPD", "Rg", "rH", "v2", "Ta", "p", 
"LWS", "rs", "cs"), day = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.25, NA, NA, -0.2745, 
0.265), `p-value...3` = c(0.01125, 0.01308, 0.1965, 0.6166, 0.0004262, 
0.1596, 0.04293, 0.0002368, 0.000393), night = c(0.4824, NA, 
-0.366, NA, 0.7316, NA, NA, 0.2352, -0.2415), `p-value...5` = c(8.46e-07, 
0.4547, 0.0002104, 0.6055, 2.2e-16, 0.8818, 0.609, 0.01325, 0.0113
)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))`
```

the Code i use for the plot is (dput):

```
 ggplot(data=Mischbewuchs, aes(`Variable`))+
  geom_bar(aes(y=`day`),stat = "identity", fill="Orange")+
  geom_bar(aes(y=`night`),stat = "identity", fill="blue", width = 0.5, position = "dodge")+
  labs(y= "Spearman rank correlation coefficient", title = "a)")+
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 0, color="black")+
  theme_bw()
```

You can see, that the part with position="dodge" does not work (Ta). Width=0,5 is for visibility only.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reshaping is the key. As you have two geom bar structures, both of them are placed in same position. Using reshape can leave you to have the expected output:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
Mischbewuchs %>% select(c(Variable,day,night)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Variable,y=value,fill=name))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.5, position = "dodge")+
  labs(y= "Spearman rank correlation coefficient", title = "a)")+
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 0, color="black")+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('orange','blue'))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Due to the reordered df, my x-Axis has the wrong order. Is there a way to rearrange that manually?

Comment: @BenjaminMabrouk You can use `factor(...,levels=yourorder,ordered=T)` or setting breaks with `scale_x_discrete()`

Comment: i found this solution which seem to be the easiest. Thank you

  xlim("VPD", "Rg", "rH", "v2","Ta","p","LWS","rS","cS")

Comment: @BenjaminMabrouk Nice, it is valid and solved your issue great!